# How can i display the custom View on my xml file?

Tags: android

[image: Snippet of my code]

As you can see in the above image, the class view is declared inside the MainActivity so it doesnot have an XML file. I want to add a button on the that custom view and manipulate it.

How can i display a custom view in xml if the class View is inside the java class that does not extends view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set any other view inside a view. [check description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), I think only [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and layouts like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` which extends `ViewGroup` can only add other views using `addView(View view)`,

*example as follows*

You can create your an xml layout file and put your custom view in it.

**example** xml file containing your custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.package.MyView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**java code** And then inflate it in a view.

```
// Inflate your xml view using layout inflater.
LayoutInflater inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View myView = (MyView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.example, null);

// now create a container class or map any of it from main_activity.xml layout.
LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);

/* LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.myLayout); */

// if you have created it programatically, set its width and height as following
linear.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    // width
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  // height

// else mention it in layout xml file.

linear.removeAllViews(); // clear layout before setting new one.

linear.addView(myView); // set custom view inside layout.
```

Now you can assign manipulate your myView anyhow. if you still want to add button. Create button in xml file and inflate or create programatically and add it to `linear.addView(View view);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout in XML, assign it a view. Then you can add the view to your other layouts. Look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) for details on creating custom views